# Getting error in Xcode no such file or directory found with libReactNativeLocalization.a during build and archive

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, xcode10

I am having issue in Xcode while I try to build or archive my react-native project. Xcode throwing error like `no such file or directory: '/Users/...../DerivedData/myproject/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReactNativeLocalization.a'`.

when I run `react-native run-ios` or in release mode `react-native run-ios --configuration Release` then it is working perfectly fine but when I try to build or archive it from Xcode then it is throwing error.

1. I am using Xcode version 10
2. My `react-native` version is 0.57.4
3. iOS development target is 9.0
4. [`react-native-localization`](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization) version is 2.0.3

**Tried things which didn't worked for me**

1. Removed node_modules and pods completely and run `npm install` and `pod install` didn't worked for me .
2. In menue File --> workspace setting changed build system from Use Shared System to Legacy build system. in this particular case app is build and archived successfully but when I lunch my app then it crashes after splash screen.
3. Removed Derived Data completely and rebuild again still getting this error.
4. If I remove [`react-native-localization`](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization) completely from my project then all the things are working fine and I am able to build and archive the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we run `react-native link react-native-localization` command then it also applies the changes on ios app too which creates an issue in our case. So due to this command, it creates an entry in  project_name →  ios → podfile [(podfile)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYGVi.png)

Here ReactNativeLocalization is pointing to project_name/node_modules/react-native-localization directory due to this line when we run pod install command then there is one dependence React in this package is going to reinstall in your pods as you can see in this image.[(as you can see here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PERbk.png)

**Follow the following steps to overcome form this issue**

- After `react-native link react-native-localization`  command navigate to **project_name → ios → podfile** and remove or comment  `pod ‘ReactNativeLocalization’, :path => ‘../node_modules/react-native-localization’`
- Now its time to link `react-native-localization` library manually from Xcode. So to link this library manually open **project_name → ios → project_name.xcworksace** file in Xcode and select your target.
- After that in project navigator right click on library and select **Add Files to “...”**  and after that navigate to **project_name → node_modules → react-native-localization** and select **ReactNativeLocalization.xcodeproj** file.
- Now navigate to project **Target → Build Phase** and expand **Link Binary With Library** after that click on plus icon and add **libReactNativeLocalization.a library**

Answer (score 0):

I had been stuck on this issue since morning. A simple hack made my build.

I observed that in folder Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ lib files were being generated in their folder. i.e libLinearGradient.a was in libLinearGradient.

One .a file which was being successfully lined was there without it's folder so I did the same for all .a files. ( Simply put them outside without their folder.)

So now path became Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libLinearGradient.a instead of Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libLinearGradient/libLinearGradient.a